# How to Invoke dynamicaly an anonymus objects function property?

Tags: c#, delegates, system.reflection, anonymous-class

I am extremely new in this area so every help will be welcomed.

So I have this anonymous object(not sure thats the correct name of it):

```
 var ERRORS = new
                {
                    ERROR   = new Func<bool>(() =>{ return true; })
                    , ERROR1  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR2  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR3  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR4  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR5  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR6  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR7  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR8  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR9  = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR10 = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR11 = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                    , ERROR12 = new Func<bool>(() => { return true; })
                };
```

I want to iterate through this object properties and call them like a function.

I have made this code so far:

```
Type type = ERRORS.GetType();
MethodInfo[] properties = type.GetMethods();

foreach (MethodInfo property in properties)
{
    Delegate del = property.CreateDelegate(typeof(System.Func<bool>));
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + del.Method.Invoke(ERRORS,null));                                                                                
}
```

This code is something i found on the Internet, made some adjustments to it but it throws exception:

> "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

It doesn't really means much to me.

As already mentioned, I am a great noob in C# so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is it really necessary to use anonymous type+reflection? why not array of Func<bool>?

Comment: well could work but still have to invoke them. Which i can't do correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create methods in an anonymous object. You can only have properties (that can be delegates)...

So:

```
Type type = ERRORS.GetType();

// Properties:
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    // Get the value of the property, cast it to the right type
    Func<bool> func = (Func<bool>)property.GetValue(ERRORS);

    // Call the delegate normally (`func()` in this case)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + func());
}
```

Note that without reflection, you can call the methods like:

```
bool res = ERRORS.ERROR1();
```

or

```
Func<bool> func = ERRORS.ERROR1();
bool res = func();
```

Note that in general what you are doing is nearly useless, because it is normally wrong to pass an anonymous object outside the function that defined it, and inside the function you already know its "shape" (you know which properties it has, and their name)

Answer (score 2):

is it really necessary to use anonymous type+reflection? why not array of Func?

example:

```
var errors = new Func<bool> [] 
{
    new Func<bool>(() => { return true; }),
    () => { return true; },
    () => { return true; },
    () => { return true; },
};

errors[0](); // take delegate by index and invoke
```